# Conditional statement to enqueue CSS in image.php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to make a new attachment page in a WordPress child theme.

I have created image.php and in my functions I am trying to get a new CSS file to load. I already have this for archive page and seems to be working OK. I have tried adding is page template (image.php) and is attachment, but doesn't seem to work

```php
if (is_archive()) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'newlayout-style' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layouts/archive.css');
} elseif (is_page_template('image.php')) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'newlayout-style' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layouts/attachment.css');
} elseif (is_attachment()) { 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'newlayout-style' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layouts/attachment.css'); 
}
```

Comment: `image.php` is a template ?

Comment: Hint: `is_attachment()` and `is_single()` both return true on `image.php`

Comment: 1. Where are you running the example code ? 2. Yes, image.php is probably not a template page but a file use by the WP template hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Two points need to be understood:

1) `is_page_template` function is useful to determine the current Page Template (if used), Page Template is different concept then Template Hierarchy. You can check in codex for further details:

[Page Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)

[Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

2) In `functions.php`, you need to determine if image attachment is getting displayed, in this case as [@PieterGoosen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1908141/pieter-goosen) has correctly pointed out, you need to use `is_single` and `is_attachment` template tags, additionally you can check if the attachment `mime-type` is image, so code should be like:

```
function add_css_conditionally() {

    if (is_archive()) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'newlayout-style' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layouts/archive.css');
    } elseif (is_single() && is_attachment()) {
        if(stripos($wp_query->post->post_mime_type, 'image') !== false) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'newlayout-style' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layouts/attachment.css'); // for image attachments, should be different css file.
        } else {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'newlayout-style' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layouts/attachment.css');
        }
    }   
}
add_filter('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_css_conditionally');
```